# Filename suffix iPad images to Asset Catalog

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, asset-catalog

Xcode Asset Catalogs have a very convenient feature in which dragging files named like this:

```
image.png
image@2x.png
image@3x.png
```

will create a single *image set* named `image` with each image placed in the right slot.

**Is there a suffix which works for iPad images?**  I'm looking for an efficient way to add ipad images to an asset catalog in the same image set as their iPhone brethren.

`~ipad` and `~iphone` after the base name only seems to work on XIB files.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since iOS4 you can use `~ipad` and `~iphone` in the following format:

*<basename><device>.<filename_extension>*

From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html):

> The  string represents the original name of the resource file. It also represents the name you use when accessing the file from your code. Similarly, the  string is the standard filename extension used to identify the type of the file. The  string is a case-sensitive string that can be one of the following values:
>
> - `~ipad` - The resource should be loaded on iPad devices only.
> - `~iphone` - The resource should be loaded on iPhone or iPod touch devices only.

Comment: That seems to be a XIB thing.  It doesn't work in asset catalogs.  Dragging in a `1x`, `@2x`, and `@3x` group of images with the same base name does stick them all in the same image set, but the ~ipad suffix doesn't do anything.

Comment: I made a [table](https://github.com/JVillella/ios-screen-sizes) to consolidate this information.